# Get Other columns based on max of one column in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, appinsights, kusto-explorer

I am trying to write a Kusto query to find record who has max value in column grouped by another column but also requires 3rd(remaining) columns with it.

Let there  be three columns A(timestamp) B(impvalue: number) and C (anothervalue:string).
I need to get records grouped by C with max timestamp and its corresponding B column too.

In Sql, I am well aware how to do it using self join. I am new to Kusto, I tried few combination with summarize, join and top operator but wasn't able to make it work.

Example:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

you can use the `arg_max()` aggregation function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/arg-max-aggfunction.

For example:

```
datatable(A:datetime, B:long, C:string)
[
    datetime(2020-08-20 12:00:00), 50,  "abc",
    datetime(2020-08-20 12:10:00), 30,  "abc",
    datetime(2020-08-20 12:05:00), 100, "abc",
    datetime(2020-08-20 12:00:00), 40,  "def",
    datetime(2020-08-20 12:05:00), 120, "def",
    datetime(2020-08-20 12:10:00), 80,  "def",
]
| summarize arg_max(A, *) by C
```

| C | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 2020-08-20 12:10:00.0000000 | 30 |
| def | 2020-08-20 12:10:00.0000000 | 80 |

Answer (score -1):

This isn't the most elegant solution, but it works:

```
let X = datatable (a: string, b: int, c: string) [
"8/24/2021, 12:40:00.042 PM", 50, "abc",
"8/24/2021, 12:40:10.042 PM", 30, "abc",
"8/24/2021, 12:40:05.042 PM", 100, "abc",
"8/24/2021, 12:40:00.042 PM", 40, "def",
"8/24/2021, 12:40:05.042 PM", 120, "def",
"8/24/2021, 12:40:10.042 PM", 80, "def"
];
X
| summarize Answer = max(a)
| join X on $left.Answer == $right.a
| project a,b,c
```

Comment: This solution is very inefficient (because of the unneeded `join`). Instead, `summarize arg_max(...)` should be used, like Yoni answered. I suggest deleting this answer.